# Cannot mount a USB exFAT drive in macOS Ventura

Tags: usb, external-disk, mount, ventura, exfat

On Windows 10 it's working perfectly without any errors.

On macOS I'm able to see it in Disk Utility, I also ran healing, but I'm still not able to mount it.

Tried various apps/drivers including Mountain, Pegasus, Hasleo and nothing worked.

Tried to kill `fsck` and also bunch of other commands and nothing worked.

Very desperate and disappointed. My 5 year old Android phone can mount it without problems.

Comment: The easiest fix is to format the drive on your Mac as FAT32.  It will compatible everywhere.

Comment: well, it's 12TB drive. Not so easy to reformat. All threads I've already read before I've posted anything. What I haven't tried is to change a location for 1mb or above... but, again, it's 12tb full of data.